# How to assign a variable inside a bash test command?

Tags: bash, shell

```
ok="1"
test -f no_such_file || (ok='0' && echo ggg)
> ggg
echo $ok
> 1
```

Why is `$ok` still `1`? How can I make it `0` in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing it this way:

```
test -f no_such_file || { ok='0'; echo ggg; }
```

The { } will give you grouping but won't start a subshell. The && wasn't useful in this case so I replaced it with ';'.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `(ok='0' && echo ggg)` is run in a subshell because it is enclosed in `()`s. If you run it without the parentheses:

```
ok="1"
test -f no_such_file || ok='0' && echo ggg
> ggg
echo $ok
> 0
```

You would have to adjust your logic to leave assignment statements outside of `()`s

Comment: Thanks Alex, but your answer produces an incorrect result - echo ggg gets executed regardless of whether no_such_file exists or not